# For each loop for objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working on converting my vbscript over to javascipt.  here is my code:

```
var colResourceIDs = swbemServices.ExecQuery("Select * from SMS_R_User WHERE [UserName] = '"+username+"');
```

I used the following for each loop in vbscript:

```
set colNameIDs = objSite.ExecQuery("select * from SMS_R_User where UserName = ' & username &'")

    for Each objNameID in colNameIDs

        wscript.echo objNameID.Division
        wscript.echo objNameID.Title
        wscript.echo objNameID.Department
        wscript.echo objNameID.physicaldeliveryOfficeName
        wscript.echo objNameID.UserName
        wscript.echo objNameID.FullUserName

    Next
```

However now I can get the values associated with each item because I am not sure how to get thru each object?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Look at the `Enumerator` object.

Comment: @Dai the Enumerator object in JavaScript?!?

Comment: Direct translation:  `for (objNameID in colNameIDs) { wscript.echo( colNameIDs[objNameID].Division); ... }` or easier to read:  `for (objNameID in colNameIDs) { var obj = colNameIDs[objNameID]; wscript.echo(obj.Division); ... }`

Comment: Please post the JavaScript you already have.

Answer (score 0):

You may iterate over the collection like this:

```
for (var key in objects) {
  // value is in object[key]
}
```